# Laravel when using @include(), {{ }} dont work inside the partial file

Tags: php, laravel, include

overview.blade.php

```
@extend('common')
@section('content')
..some html code     
@endsection
```

common.blade.php

```
..some html code
@include('includes.nav')
@yield('content')
..some html code
```

include/nav.php

```
<a href="{{ route('inventory') }} ">Inventory</a>
```

The above code prints out {{ route('inventory') }} in the browser and not the value.

[sample result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv8ZA.png)

When I tried it on overview.blade.php, it worked well.

[sample result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhyu.png)

Your help will be well appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `include/nav.php` to `include/nav.blade.php` since you want Laravel Blade engine compile this file.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#introduction):

> Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file extension and are typically stored in the `resources/views` directory.